# Weird Xcode 6 Beta 4 [UIImage imageNamed:] behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcode6, imagenamed

Historically I've successfully used the == comparator when comparing an image in an imageView to some predefined image using [UIImage imageNamed:]. This is because I receive the same object when calling [UIImage imageNamed:] repeatedly with the same filename, such as:

```
(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a1433a0>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a1433a0>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a1433a0>
```

Using Xcode 6 Beta 4, a number of my unit tests are failing when trying to compare an image in an imageView to an expected image, and it seems that is because I am given a unique instance of the image with a given filename each time, rather than the old behavior explained above. When doing the same thing in Xcode 6 Beta 4, I get this:

```
(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a691f00>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a6a1d00>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a1f3230>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7a6a1fd0>
```

Is this expected behavior, something I'm missing in the documentation for UIImage, perhaps an implementation issue I should address differently, or is this something I should file with Apple as a bug? Any insights?

Comment: what iOS version did you build it with?

Comment: In Xcode 5 it's 7.1 and I'll have to check but I assume its 8.0 in the beta.

Comment: In iOS 7.1 it works normally for me the inconsistence is here only with iOS 8

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same thing in iOS 7 and I had the expected output (i.e same object for all vars)
But when I run the same thing in iOS 8 I get different objects. (Both times using Xcode 6 beta 4)

So I checked the docs for [iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) we have:

```
 +(UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
```

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object
>   with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a
>   matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads
>   the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns
>   the resulting object.

[iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:):

```
 +(UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
```

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and
>   loads the image data from disk or asset catalog, and then returns the
>   resulting object. You can not assume that this method is thread safe.

There is nothing in the seconde text that specifies exactly that this call caches the data, so maybe it's attended (Which doesn't make any sense) or it's a bug.
My advice is to send a bug report, and see what they'll say.

Ayu.

Comment: That's what I was about to say. Good spirit Ayu.

Comment: Bug sent - although the last bug report I filed back in March is still unanswered, so we'll see. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible they changed the underlying caching behavior and forgot to update the documentation.  Can you post the bug tracker id so we can monitor it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare objects by their instances addresses if what you want is to compare their content!

Sure it works sometimes by coincidence but there is no guarantee—as you have found out.

Apple is free to change such implementation details at will without notice.

Write your own compare method, perhaps comparing just an initial portion since this is test code.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "coincidence". The documentation says that it imageNamed returns ".. the image object associated with the specified filename.", it doesn't say AN image, it says THE image. So how can you test to see if an image in an imageView is "foo.png" if not with ==?

Comment: See updated answer. You need to compare the contents. There are short-cuts if you are willing to sacrifice 100% surety. Perhaps compare the addresses and if they don't match comparing the contents or a portion, see the answer re: write your own compare method.

Comment: Re comment: file a documentation bug with Apple since you find this confusing.

Comment: So you're saying that I shouldn't expect this to always work: 
UIImage *fooImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]; 
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fooImage];
iv.image == fooImage

Comment: Yes, do not expect that to work. The rule has always been not to compare addresses if it is the content that needs to be compared.

Comment: This should solve the problem in this case (and as stated it's not safe/sure to compare objects with instance adresses), but the fact that there is a new instance each time for the same image using imageNamed is a strange behavior.

Comment: I'm not expecting to compare the content - I'm expecting that both variables are referencing the same image object originally created. Likely a byref vs byval issue on my part that only manifests now in iOS8.